# How to upgrade Nativescript app to version 6?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Recently I tried to upgrade my nativescript5.1.1 app to nativescript6 and I am getting the following error:

> ```
> ERROR in ./tools/preinstall.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/saiful/Documents/Workspaces/test-App/app/tools'
> @ ./tools/preinstall.js 3:13-37
> @ . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$*
> @ ./app.js
> ```

Comment: What's your node version? Does this happen when you run the upgrade command?

Comment: @Manoj --- My Node version is 'v10.16.3' . And it happens when I run the app 'tns run ios'. Thanks

Comment: @Manoj --After Migrating I got some warnings and errors but Still App is running with lots of bugs. I am trying to solve all the warnings and errors but could not solve this 'child_process' error. And App has lots of bugs as well.

Comment: Short imports on tns core moduels are deprecated now, did you update the import / require statements?

Comment: @Manoj ..did you mean to add 'tns-core-modules/' on every require statements? In that case i did not add them till now as app was running. Should i Add them manually on each require field?

Comment: Yes, if it's from tns-core-modules.

Comment: @Manoj -- I have updated all the require statements .. and still i have the same error and bugs as well.

Comment: Did you upgrade webpack version and config as part of upgrade. What other bugs you see in log?

Comment: @Manoj-- Yes I have upgraded webpack version . Actually in log I have only that 'child_process' error nothing else. And on the app, all the buttons are missing and infor buttons are displaced.

Comment: @Manoj-- My app works perfectly on version 5.1 but only in Simulator. whenever I make an ipa and install on device its totally different from the simulator. if I try to run on device during development I get the the message "Unable to change ....- Could not start service com.apple.mobile.house_arrest"

Comment: And ALL these issues have appeared since ios 13 launched.#

Comment: I'm using both 6.x and 5.4 with Xcode 11 / iOS 13. Did you give a try for creating a new project via CLI, see if you are able to install / debug the new app?